# How to get method/function in a string by using regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I trying to get arguments from function in the string.

Argument possible to contains:

#### Example

***Placeholder:***

```
{{request.expires_in}}
//can match regex: \{\{[a-zA-z0-9\.\-\_]\}\}
```

***function***

```
@func_compare('string1','string2',1234)
```

***Others:***

```
dERzUxOfnj49g/kCGLR3vhzBOTLwEMgrpa1/MCBpXQR2NIFV1yjraGVZLkujG63J0joj+TvNocjpJSQq2TpPRzLfCSZADcjmbkBkphIpsT8=
//Any string except brackets
```

---

#### Case

Below is the sample case I working with.

***Content:***

```
@func_compare('string1',@func_test(2),1234),'Y-m-d H:i:s',@func_strtotime({{request.expires_in}} - 300)
```

***Regex using:***

```
(?<=@func_compare\().*[^\(](?=\))
```

***I expect will get***

```
'string1',@func_test(2),1234
```

***But what matched from the regex now is***

```
'string1',@func_test(2),1234),'Y-m-d H:i:s',@func_strtotime({{request.expires_in}} - 300
```

Anyone know how to get the arguments in between the @func_strtotime brackets. I will appreciate any response.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try:

```
(?<=@func_compare\().*?(?:\(.*?\).*?)?(?=\))
```

which will work for both cases.

**[Explanation of the regex]**

```
.*?(?:\(.*?\).*?)?(?=\))

.*?                       the shortest match not to overrun the next pattern
   (?:\(.*?\).*?)?        a group of substring which includes a pair of parens followed by another substring of length 0 or longer
                  (?=\))  positive lookahead for the right paren
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The regex unable to get expected match result

Comment: @Deno thank you for the feedback. Do you desire a unified regex which will work for the both of previous string and the new string? Or a solution just for the new one is acceptable?

Comment: Yes, need to work for both previous and new string. The possible match string I have listed on my answer example part.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I've updated my answer accordingly. Would you please test it? BR.

Comment: Thank again for the response. Your answer if almost perfect. Just unable to cover some circumstance like 

@func_compare('str',@func_test('1',@func_test('2')),'str',@func_test('3'))
and
@func_compare('str',@func_test('1',@func_test('2')),'str')

I think my problem unable to just use regex to solve it. Anyway, thank for your patient and kind help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the result using recursive regex:

```
(?<=@func_compare\()([^()]*\((?:.*?\)|(?1))*)[^()]*(?=\))
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/7BLKC3/2)